# When I change the Media Query breakpoint in Sass the Flex does not work

Tags: html, css, sass, responsive-design

I'm a beginner and I'm building a page using HTML5 and Sass
I have a section and gave it display: flex; justify-content: space-around
, and I want it on the mobile screen, flex-direction: column;
Here the problem appears and it does not work
I need help
Thanks
Media: https://github.com/wrongakram/sass-mediaqueries/blob/master/src/breakpoints/breakpoints.scss

**index.html**

```
<section class="hero-section" id="home">
        <div class="hero-left-part col-md-6">
            <div class="hero-dot">
                <img src="./images/orange-dot.svg" alt="orange dot">
                <p class="main-color">#1 Editiors Choice App of 2020</p>
            </div>
            <h1 class="main-color">Best app for your modern lifestyle</h1>
            <p>
                Increase productivity with a simple to-do app. app for
                managing your personal budgets.
            </p>
            <div class="hero-button">
                <button>Try for free</button>
                <p>Watch demo video</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="hero-right-part">
            <img src="./images/smart-phone.png" alt="smart-phone">
        </div>
    </section>
```

**style.scss**

```
@import "./breackpoints.scss";
.hero-section {
    margin-top: 2rem;
    @include flex-around;
    background: url('./images/Layer.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: bottom;

    .hero-left-part {
        width: 40%;

        .hero-dot {
            display: flex;
            margin-left: 1rem;

            img {
                width: 2.4rem;
                position: absolute;
                left: 5.9rem;
                margin-top: 0.8rem;
            }

            p {
                // position: relative;
                font-size: 18px;
                background-color: #e2eaed;
                padding: 0.2rem 2.2rem;
                border-radius: 5rem;
                margin-top: 0.8rem
            }
        }

        h1 {
            font-size: 60px;
            font-weight: $weight-600;
        }

        p {
            margin-top: 1rem;
            color: #616368;
            font-size: 18px;
        }

        .hero-button {
            @include flex-around;

            button {
                @include button;
            }

            p {
                font-size: 1.1rem;
                color: blue;
                font-weight: 500;
            }
        }
    }
    @include media ('<=tablet'){
        .hero-left-part{
            .hero-dot {
                img{
                    left:2.9rem;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @include media ('<=phone'){
        .hero-section{
            flex-direction: column;
        }
    }
}
```

**breakpoints:**
https://github.com/wrongakram/sass-mediaqueries/blob/master/src/breakpoints/breakpoints.scss

```
$breakpoints: (
    "phone": 768px,
    "tablet": 992px,
    "desktop": 1366px,
    "LGdesktop": 1920px) !default;
```

Comment: Also add `flex-around` mixin.

Comment: still not working

Comment: No I mean, add the complete scss in the question. `flex-around` mixin is not there in the provided scss code.

Comment: Can you show the code for `media`?

Comment: @AbhaySrivastav mixin flex-around {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
}

Comment: Also for `media`, better add in the question code itself.

Comment: Media:  https://github.com/wrongakram/sass-mediaqueries/blob/master/src/breakpoints/breakpoints.scss